PermissionDenied: 403 You do not have permission to access tuned model
I have tuned a gemini base model and wrote a python code to access it but unfortunatelly I keep getting the error "PermissionDenied: 403 You do not have permission to access tuned model".
I have read instructions to set a OAuth 2.0 Client ID and I think I did it right since the authentication worked, but the prompt does not.
Bellow is the code I am trying to run.
import os
import gspread
import google.generativeai as genai
from load_creds import load_creds

creds = load_creds()

genai.configure(credentials=creds)

# Configure the API key for the Google Generative AI
genai.configure(api_key="My API key")

# Configuration for text generation 
generation_config = {
    "temperature": 0.9,
    "top_p": 0.95,
    "top_k": 64,
    "max_output_tokens": 1024,
    "response_mime_type": "text/plain",
}

# Create a GenerativeModel instance
model = genai.GenerativeModel(
    model_name="tunedModels/mytunedmodel",
    generation_config=generation_config,
)

# Start a chat session
chat_session = model.start_chat(enable_automatic_function_calling=True)

# Send a message to the chat session including the file URI
response = chat_session.send_message(f"Good morning")

# Print the response
print(response.text)"



This is my access tuned model example.  It just tests that i can make requests to all the models I have tuned currently.
I believe you are missing
genai.configure(transport='grpc')

full sample
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import google.generativeai as genai

load_dotenv()

genai.configure(api_key=os.getenv("API_KEY"))
genai.configure(transport='grpc')


def get_response(use_tuned_model, text):
    try:
        print(f"Making request: {text} against Model: {use_tuned_model}")
        model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name=use_tuned_model)
        response = model.generate_content(text)
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: ", e)


def list_my_tuned_models():
    models = []
    for m in genai.list_tuned_models():
        print(f"Name: {m.name} Description: {m.description} Created: {m.create_time} Base Model: {m.base_model}")
        models.append(m.name)
    return models


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tuned_models = list_my_tuned_models()

    for tuned_model in tuned_models:
        get_response(tuned_model, "55")

    tuned_model = "tunedModels/youtube-titles"
    get_response(tuned_model, "a emoji video")

Env var
You need an env var set to the path of your credentials file I just put it in the .env file.

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Development\GoogleSamples\Credentials\gemini-407220-ea106e0d696d.json


Hi Linda. Thank you for you response. I tried you code and I got an error, it seems my authentication has issues, just can´t figure out: ------- raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
key: "service"
value: "generativelanguage.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
key: "method"
value: "google.ai.generativelanguage.v1beta.ModelService.ListTunedModels"
}
]

I will have to check my code again in the morning I may have forgotten the environment variables

you need to set the env var GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\gemini-407220-ea106e0d696d.json
